# How to prevent findOneAndUpdate update certain keywords to a column?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a user management system where admin has the rights to update the role of their users, how to prevent admin from updating a document with roles higher than him?
Example, order of authority in descending order:
1: superadmin
2: admin
3: supervisor
4: user

Now I have a code which updates the role of a user as:

```
router.post('/changeRole', async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  const updatedUser = await Users.findOneAndUpdate({ email }, { $set: { role } }, { new: true });
  }
);
```

By the above code admin could make anyone a superdmin and it would give that user every access. Is there a way something like this below to prevent that in query?

```
router.post('/changeRole', async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  const updatedUser = await Users.findOneAndUpdate({ email }, { $set: { role !== "superadmin" } }, { new: true });
  }
);
```

Comment: can't you check the role before updating? and if its not allowed, send an alternate response, without updating the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help you:

```js
const updatedUser = await Users.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        email: email,
        role: {$ne: "superadmin"}
    }, 
    { $set: role },
    { new: true }
);
```

`$ne` operator means `not equal`, so this only updates the document when email matches and role is different from `superadmin`.